# How can I make search bar searches only my website pages and give suggetions

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make search bar searches only my website pages and give suggetions

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Check the tutorial here. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

Comment: I maked google search engine but not help me @Dula

Comment: Thanks but this code is too long 
@seantsang94121

Comment: What do you mean "too long"? That code is only as long as it needs to be. However you're right in the sense that I'm pretty certain it wouldn't solve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below link, you may get a chance to go next step

https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4513903?hl=en#zippy=%2Chow-do-i-change-the-language-of-the-search-engine

1. From the google [control panel](http://cse.google.com/all), select the search engine you want to edit.
2. Click Setup from the menu on the left and then click the Basics tab.
3. Click Get code.
4. Copy the code and paste it into your site’s HTML source code where you want your search engine to appear. If you've chosen the two column or two page layout option, you'll need to copy and paste two snippets of code:

- Paste the first code snippet where you want the search box to appear.
- Paste the second code snippet where you want the search results to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample HTML and js form code for search bar:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('searchform').onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yourdomainname ' + document.getElementById('test').value;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

```html
<form id="sarchform" class="search2" method="get" action="source.html" />
<input class="search2" id="test" type="text" name="search" size="10" maxlength="255"/>
```

Comment: Thanks , I hope there are more answers  to my question ,That helps me

Comment: How to make it open the search result page